# How to create a style or theme on swift so I can set color to all UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

It seems to be pretty obvious but I couldn't find much about it after hours.

I'm build an App on swift 2.0 and I have a dark background to all views.

I want to set a common background and color to all my text views, people recommend that each view should set the properties on viewDidLoad, but I don't want to set to each textView one by one the same information. It will be a hell to maintain.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically yes, each one should be done separately so that you have more control over things. However, if you want to change the background color of all of your text fields you can do it like this:

```
UITextField.appearance().backgroundColor = //Your color
```

You can also change the caret color using this:

```
UITextField.appearance().tintColor = //Your color
```

If you want to change these colors for a `UITextView` then simply swap `UITextField.appearance()...` for `UITextView.appearance()...`

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `UITextView` and set the properties to what you desire in the `init` method. Then have each of your `UITextView` have a Custom Class set to your `UITextView` subclass.

Example:

```
class UITextViewSubclass: UITextView {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

With this approach, you could also declare some `@IBInspectable` properties which means they can be modified from the Inspector, if you want to change this color from the Inspector instead of changes inside your code.

```
class UITextViewSubclass: UITextView {
    @IBInspectable var customBackgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = customBackgroundColor
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        backgroundColor = customBackgroundColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `UIAppearance` with to change all `UITextView`, or you can subclass `UITextView` and modify the object after initialisation, then use that subclass instead of `UITextView`.